# Ctrl+Alt+1 is not working in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, hotkeys

According to the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#ID0EDHBTBBJBF) the following should work in MS Word:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> should apply the Heading 1 style. In my case it acts as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> should apply the Heading 2 style. In my case it works.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> should apply the Heading 3 style. In my case it acts as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

How to make <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Word you can customize the keyboard shortcuts. Go to *File* > *Options* > *Customize Ribbon*. On the bottom next to *Keyboard shortcuts:* static text click *Customize*.

[image]

In *Categories* choose *Commands Not in the Ribbon* or *All Commands*. In *Commands* choose *ApplyHeading1*. Click into *Press new shortcut key:* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. You will see what it is currently assigned to. In my case it was something like *[apply prefix]*.

[image]

The solution is to reassign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to *ApplyHeading1*, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to *ApplyHeading3*. Then the *Currently assigned to* will show *ApplyHeading1* and *ApplyHeading3* respectively, and the shortcuts will work as documented.

Clearly a bug in Word. On another computer I didn't see it, so it comes only under specific circumstances.

Comment: What happens if you start Word in Safe Mode?
If it works in Safe Mode, an Add-In is interfering with these shortcuts.
https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72